# Why do we have to import a providers again inside component [Angular2]

Tags: angular

According to [Working With Shared Providers In A NativeScript Angular 2 App](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/11/working-shared-providers-nativescript-angular-2-app/)

It mentions :-

> Yes we had already imported the provider into the `@NgModule`, but it
>   is not the same. It needs to be done in both places.

Why?

Comment: did you try as i dnt think so it is necessary . ngmodule is fine

Comment: Yes, didn't work. Spits an error that component is missing or undefined.